# Angular Material Scrollbar on Card Content Enclosed in a Tab

Tags: html, css, angular-material, scrollbar

Please help with a problem I'm having styling angular material tabs.

See:  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6-material-tab-problem?file=app/tab.component.html
[Edit:  The stackblitz example is working as expected after making the changes that I noted in my answer]

The first tab is close to how I'd like it:

1. Overflow-y scrollbar is available when content in mat-card-content
   exceeds visible space in tab.
2. No scrollbars on the mat-card or mat-tab Should be able to
   appropriately resize.
3. On window resize, for example, the height of the mat-tab-group could
   grow taller -- the mat-card-content should also grow taller and be
   scrollable, if needed.

[image]

There is a problem though when the length of the contents in the mat-card-content don't exceed the height of the tab.

For example, with the same styling though, the second tab isn't right.  The red rectangle of the mat-card should fill the height of the mat-tab.  There is also a scrollbar on the far right which isn't needed.

[image]

Here is the template:

```
<mat-tab-group>
  <mat-tab label="Properties">
    <mat-card class="scrollable-content">
      <mat-card-header>
          <mat-card-title>Card Data</mat-card-title>
      </mat-card-header>
      <mat-card-content>
          My Content for this card...<br>
          0 Lots and lots of content.<br>
          1 Lots and lots of content.<br>
          2 Lots and lots of content.<br>
          3 Lots and lots of content.<br>
          4 Lots and lots of content.<br>
          5 Lots and lots of content.<br>
          6 Lots and lots of content.<br>
          7 Lots and lots of content.<br>
          8 Lots and lots of content.<br>
          9 Lots and lots of content.<br>
          10 Lots and lots of content.<br>
          11 Lots and lots of content.<br>
          12 Lots and lots of content.<br>
          13 Lots and lots of content.<br>
          14 Lots and lots of content.<br>
          15 Lots and lots of content.<br>
          16 Lots and lots of content.<br>
          17 Lots and lots of content.<br>
          18 Lots and lots of content.<br>
          19 Lots and lots of content.<br>
          20 Lots and lots of content.<br>
          21 Lots and lots of content.<br>
          22 Lots and lots of content.<br>
          23 Lots and lots of content.<br>
      </mat-card-content>
    </mat-card>
  </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="2nd Tab">
    <mat-card  class="scrollable-content">
      <mat-card-header>
          <mat-card-title>Other Stuff</mat-card-title>
      </mat-card-header>
      <mat-card-content>
        2nd Tab
      </mat-card-content>
    </mat-card>
  </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

And here is the CSS:

```
.mat-card.scrollable-content{
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.mat-card.scrollable-content mat-card-content {
    overflow-y: auto;
}
.mat-card.scrollable-content mat-card-title {
    display: block;
}

.mat-tab-group {
  height: 400px;
  border: 2px solid #00F;
}

.mat-card-content {
  border: 2px solid #0F0
}
.mat-card-title {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.25em !important;
}
.mat-card {
  border: 2px solid #F00;
  height: 85%;
}

.mat-tab-label{
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.25em;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem after realizing that the material design elements used in the template get preprocessed into other css classes.

I got it working by adding the following to the css:

```
.mat-tab-body-content {
  overflow: hidden !important;
}

.mat-tab-body-wrapper {
  height: 100% !important;
}
```